# If $m^*(E)=\infty$, then how can $E$ be expressed as the disjoint union of a countable collection of measurable sets, each with finite outer measure?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Here is my question.

> Let $E$ be a measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $m^*(E) = \infty$. Then how to express $E$ as the union of a countable disjoint collection of measurable sets, each of which has finite outer measure?

Context: Proof of Theorem 11, Sec. 2.4, in the book *Real Analysis* by H.L. Royden and P.M. Fitzpatrick, 4th edition.

By definition, $m^*(E)$ is the infimum of the set of all the sums $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty l \left( I_k \right)$, where $\left\{ I_k \right\}_{k = 1}^\infty$ is a countable collection of non-empty, bounded open intervals covering $E$.

As $m^*(E) = \infty$, so for any countable collection $\left\{ I_k \right\}_{k = 1}^\infty$ of non-empty, bounded open intervals covering $E$, we must have
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^\infty l \left( I_k \right) = \infty. 
$$

How to proceed from here?

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan I'm extremely sorry for the inconvenience, but I just forgot to include one very important condition on set $E$. So can you please have a look at my edited post and modify your answer accordingly? I would be immensely grateful!

Comment: How about the collection $\{E \cap [n,n+1) \mid n \in \mathbb Z\}$?

Comment: If you set $E$ is Lebesgue measurable at the very beginning, it is better to write $m(E)=\infty$ instead of $m^\ast(E)=\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible. For, if it is true, then every set that has infinite outer measure would be Lebesgue measurable. Recall that there exists a non Lebesgue measurable set $A$ in $[0,1]$. We must have $m^\ast(A)>0$ because every set that has zero outer-measure is Lebesgue measurable. Define $B = \cup_{n=1}^\infty (A+n)$, then $m^\ast(B)=\infty$. However, $B$ cannot be Lebesgue measurable because if $B$ is Lebesgue measurable, then $A = B\cap[0,1]$ would be Lebesgue measurable too.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for the inconvenience, but I just forgot to include one very important condition on set $E$. So can you please have a look at my edited post and modify your answer accordingly? I would be immensely grateful!